# Sandbox Paypal Money Deduction Issues

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

#### My code:

```
function paiement_echec()
    {
    echo "payment cancelled by the user";
    }

function paiement_succes()
{
  // Obtain the token from PayPal.
  if(!array_key_exists('token', $_REQUEST)) 
         exit('Token is not received.');
  // Set request-specific fields.
  $token = urlencode(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['token']));
  // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
  $nvpStr = "&TOKEN=$token";
  // Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
  $httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $nvpStr);
  if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
      {
          //print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
          $payerID = urlencode($httpParsedResponseAr["PAYERID"]);
          //$token = urlencode("token");
          $paymentType = urlencode('Sale');         // or 'Sale' or 'Order'
          $paymentAmount = urlencode("4.39");
          $currencyID = urlencode("USD");                       // or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
 
// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
          $nvpStr = "&TOKEN=$token&PAYERID=$payerID&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$paymentAmount&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";
          $httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $nvpStr);
           if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
           {
             $this->load->model('payment_model');
             $this->payment_model->paypal_payment();
             $msg = "<label>Thank you !! your payment is successfully done</label>
              <a href='".base_url()."envoie_de_photos/envoyer_vos_photos"."'>Go To Photo Uploading</a>";
             echo $msg;
           }
          else  
            {
                 exit('GetExpressCheckoutDetails failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
             //echo "Payment failed for unknown reason";
            }
      } 
  else  
      {
        //exit('GetExpressCheckoutDetails failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
        echo "Payment failed for unknown reason";
      }
}


function pay_by_paypal()
{
  
        $environment = 'sandbox';
        $_SESSION['item_name']=$this->input->post('item_name');
        $_SESSION['amount']=$this->input->post('amount');
        $_SESSION['currency_code']=$this->input->post('currency_code');
        $_SESSION['no_of_photo']=$this->input->post('no_of_photo');
        
        $qty=urlencode("1");
        $product_name=urldecode($_SESSION['item_name']);
        $price=urlencode($_SESSION['amount']);
        //$currencyID = urlencode($_SESSION['currency_code']);
        $currencyID = urlencode("USD");

        
  
// or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
     $paymentType = urlencode('Order'); 
     $nvpStr=""; 
     $returnURL = (base_url()."paiement/paiement_succes");
     $cancelURL = (base_url()."paiement/paiement_echec");  
     $i=0;
     $total_amount=0;
     
     $str = "&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&RETURNURL=$returnURL
&CANCELURL=$cancelURL
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=$product_name
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=$qty
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=$price
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=$product_name
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=$price
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID"; 
     $nvpStr=$nvpStr.$str;
$httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $nvpStr);
     
if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]))
    {
    // Redirect to paypal.com.
    $token = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"]);
    $payPalURL = "https://www.$environment.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
    if("sandbox" === $environment) 
            {
        $payPalURL = "https://www.$environment.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
    }
    header("Location: $payPalURL");
    exit;
} 
else  
    {
    exit('SetExpressCheckout failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}
  
}

/** SetExpressCheckout NVP example; last modified 08MAY23.
 *
 *  Initiate an Express Checkout transaction. 
*/


/**
 * Send HTTP POST Request
 *
 * @param   string  The API method name
 * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
 * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
 */
private function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
    //global $environment;
        $environment = 'sandbox';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'
    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $API_UserName = urlencode('saswat_1360720799_biz_api1.gmail.com');
    $API_Password = urlencode('1360720821');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('ApDCeFez-N1Gd1-O3ubTGdpyiow4AlNlRemm8XJFcbsA.WbSMtlMSqHf');
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('65.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}
```

I have three accounts in the Paypal sandbox: two business and one personal. All of my Paypal accounts have USD as default currency.

In the above code I was using EUR as a currency.

When I am carrying out transaction, if I am paying from my personal (buyer) account in EUR, then my buyer account is getting money deducted (equivalent amount of USD is getting subtracted from my buyer account). This is totally fine, there is no issue with that.

The problem is that no amount is getting added to my business or (seller) account.

I found a post on Stack Overflow that reads:

> if the currencycode of the transaction and the seller account doesnt
> match, then money doesnt get aded to sellers account

I changed the euro to USD, (since my sandbox seller test account is in USD) and found out that, after converting it into USD, then my money is getting added to my seller account.

Is this a problem with the sandbox only, or does it apply to live paypal as well?

I have a site where buyers can pay in GBP, EUR, MYN, SGD, AUD.

If the transaction needs to be carried out in particular currency, that is the currency set as per the seller account, then there's no need to use different currencies.

Since the currencyCode which is passed in SetExpressCheckOut should match with the DoExpressCheckout, and as I have faced problem, currencyCode needs to be same as that of sandbox seller account, so even if buyers are selecting GBP, I have to send it to SetExpressCheckout as the currencyCode of the seller account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the currencies you would like to receive payments in through the control panel of your business account in question.

Go to `Profile` -> `My Settings` -> Financial Information tab and `Currency Balances`. From there select a currency and add it to the list. Your received payments are then kept in the respective currency balance they were made until you convert them to whatever you want.

Comment: this thing seemed interesting........but the thing which you are telling, is this for original paypal seller account, or just the sandbox paypal........... i cant check it out with original paypal account as i dont have any..

Comment: @Saswat They are identical on this matter. You can check [paypal's developer instructions](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/admin/setup-acccount#id095FF400OPF) for this particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default, transactions that take place in a currency you don't hold are held until you decide what to do with them.  If you log into the seller account in question, you should see the transaction listed under your history.  You should be able to accept it or deny it from there.

There are two ways around this:

- Add Euros as a currency balance to your seller's account, as Alderis noted.
- Have all transactions that take place in a currency you don't hold automatically accepted and converted to USD.  To do this, log into the seller's account, click on **Profile**, then click on **Payment Receiving Preferences** (in the **Selling preferences** column), then set **Block payments sent to me in a currency I do not hold** to **No, accept them and convert them to U.S. Dollars**, then click **Save**.