# Paypal Direct pay not working

Tags: php, paypal

I have api for Paypal DoDirect Method on NVP [Direct Credit Card Payment], and I'm using php as base language.

I'm getting success with the transaction Or the response says so. But its not updating in the sandbox account.

```
    include_once(drupal_get_path('module','payment_details').'/paypal_do_direct.php');
    $paypalDoDirect = new PaypalDoDirect();
    $paypalDoDirect->setApiUserName('crazyheartram_api1.gmail.com');
    $paypalDoDirect->setApiPassword('1377690526');
    $paypalDoDirect->setApiSignature('Afm3wtXOE0L1wd2UrjZtljZHC-wnAWHTSwJ-b7-rw3qPcLGaMSLINqP8');
    $paypalDoDirect->setCreditCardType($cardType);
    $paypalDoDirect->setEnvironment('sandbox'); 
    $paypalDoDirect->setAmount($amount);
    $paypalDoDirect->setCardExpMonth($expirationDate);
    $paypalDoDirect->setCardExpYear($expirationYear);
    $paypalDoDirect->setCardVerificationValue($cvv);
    $paypalDoDirect->setFirstName($firstName);
    $paypalDoDirect->setLastName($lastName);
    $paypalDoDirect->setPayerEmail($email);
    $paypalDoDirect->setCreditCardNumber($creditCardNumber);
    $response= $paypalDoDirect->MakePayment();
```

I shared my sandbox bussiness-pro account details below:

```
Username: crazyheartram_api1.gmail.com
Password: 1377690526
Signature: Afm3wtXOE0L1wd2UrjZtljZHC-wnAWHTSwJ-b7-rw3qPcLGaMSLINqP8
```

And I did the transaction using my another personal account.

```
Credit card number: 4351521550740304
Credit card type: Visa
Expiration date: 7/2018
```

My expectation is, it should deduct the amount from personal account and credit it to the merchant (business-pro) account.

Any help highly appreciated. Thanks

**EDITED**
I'm using same code as mentioned in below url,
[Payment Api using class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439015/payment-api-using-class)

I just found this question, its exactly the same question as that of mine.
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82788/seperate-payment-integeration-for-selected-plan-type-using-drupal-form-with-payp

Comment: downvoter, can u pls give clarification on why was it down voted?

Comment: I guess the downvoter expected you to show your code? my 2 cents

Comment: Hello @pown please send some more information in your code which value you have sending to paypal.

Comment: Login authentication failed. I thnk you have given wrong username

Comment: I think he has not given the details, just example variables he has assigned here.

Comment: Yes, shared credentials are accounts created inside my developer account (as mentioned by Ram). I've not shared my paypal account details here.

Comment: I'm getting 'success' as response. But its not deducting anything from my sandbox personal account

Comment: @pown please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845730/sandbox-paypal-money-deduction-issues
might be of your consern

Comment: @RajeevRanjan: I really appreciate the response. my problem is, I'm getting transaction response "success" but its not getting reflecting in paypal sandbox account that I used for the transaction. The link you shared is totally different in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DoDirectPayment` call charges credit cards directly; it does not deduct from a PayPal account - even if that card is attached to an existing PayPal account. Therefore it doesn't show up as a transaction in your 'buyer' PayPal account.

Comment: So what you are saying is that if i provide a valid credit number with some money in it and try to use it in DoDirectPayment method,  the actual moment will be deducted from the credit card.Is that Right?

Comment: That's right. DoDirectPayment charges immediately by default. If you want you can create an authorization (PAYMENTACTION=Authorization) and capture this later via our DoCapture API call, but essentially, yes.