# Separate Payment Integeration For Selected plan type using Drupal Form with Paypal API

Tags: forms, payment, payment-gateway

I have used a normal class as an API and in that U am passing all the parameters to paypal and i am getting success.

Only thing i am missing is that amount is not being deducted from the sandbox account.

Where as if i pay amount for buying a product by using `checkout with paypal` the actual amount is being deducted in my sandbox account.

What could be the reason? Is there any other alternative way where i can able to use paypal to receive money through passed arguments in payment details form.

In the submit function of the drupal form i am calling like this.

```
$paypalDoDirect = new PaypalDoDirect();

// passing all parameters to $paypalDoDirect

$response= $paypalDoDirect->MakePayment();
```

I am getting transaction is successful and every parameters are getting passed sucessfully.

This is my class api-

```
class PaypalDoDirect
{

    /**Declared all fields **/
    function MakePayment()
    {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
        if ("sandbox" === $this->environment || "beta-sandbox" === $this->environment) {
            $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$this->environment.paypal.com/nvp";
        }

        // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
        $nvpStr = "&PAYMENTACTION=$this->paymentType&AMT=$this->amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$this->cc_type&ACCT=$this->cc_number" .
            "&EXPDATE=$this->expdate_month$this->expdate_year&CVV2=$this->cvv2_number&FIRSTNAME=$this->first_name&LASTNAME=$this->last_name&EMAIL=$this->email" .
            "&STREET=$this->address1&CITY=$this->city&STATE=$this->state&ZIP=$this->zip&COUNTRYCODE=$this->country&CURRENCYCODE=$this->currencyID";

        //$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('DoDirectPayment', $nvpStr);

        $methodName_ = 'DoDirectPayment';
        $nvpStr_ = $nvpStr;

        // Set the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
        $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$this->version&PWD=$this->API_Password&USER=$this->API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$this->API_Signature$nvpStr_";
        // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);
        // Get response from the server.
        $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
        if (!$httpResponse) {
            return ("$methodName_ failed: " . curl_error($ch) . '(' . curl_errno($ch) . ')');
        }
        // Extract the response details.
        $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);
        $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
        foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
            $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
            if (sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
                $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
            }
        }
        if ((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
            exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
        }
        if ("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return (urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What i can able to understand is that, you are trying to call that MakePayment function inside a submit handler of drupal form which has payment details form?

Comment: Yes that's what i am doing. The response of that function i am getting is successful transaction, but no money is being deducted from my sandbox account. 

Where as if i checkout a product using paypal, money is being deducted from the sandbox account. 

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does any one used something like this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paypal Direct pay not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487987/paypal-direct-pay-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you looking for,

[Paypal Direct pay not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487987/paypal-direct-pay-not-working)

**Exerpt:**
The DoDirectPayment call charges credit cards directly; it does not deduct from a PayPal account - even if that card is attached to an existing PayPal account. Therefore it doesn't show up as a transaction in our 'buyer' PayPal account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a [paypal API](https://drupal.org/project/paypal_api) module in drupal. It's a nice structured module to extend paypal IPN in some custom module.

If you use this module, IPN callback will be handled by this module & you can get notification of it by `hook_paypal_api_ipn()` at your instance. If you go though paypal documentation about handling payment with paypal & look into the module code, you will understand the mechanism to use it well. I will recommend you to use this module.

Though you can create your own module to handle paypal payment either express or forward users there. I have done it once with drupal instance long ago. You will have to send users or data(for express) at given URL for your account with some information & what ever happens in there(pass/fail/terminate), paypal will inform you at your mentioned callback URL of your instance. Receive the info & do work accordingly..

Comment: Thanks for the input.I have actually edited the question.You can let know your thoughts on it.

Comment: Any thoughts on paypalDoDirect class and Why amount is not getting deducted?

Comment: @Ram - Nope. I will have to look into my old code, will see how I did when I had to..If I find that instance I will reply you for sure..